# OLS estimator (matrix form)

Tags: statistics, economics, parameter-estimation

I got the statistical model:
$y = β_1x_1 + β_2x_2 + u$.
Then I have to write this as matrix problem and find the OLS estimator $\beta$^. I know that $\beta^=(X^tX)^{-1}X^ty$. So I think it's possible for me to find if I know the matrices. Can someone help me to write down the matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $m$ data points then

$$X=\begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ x_{21} & x_{22} \\ x_{31} & x_{32} \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ x_{m1} & x_{m2}\end{pmatrix}, \ y=\begin{pmatrix} y_1  \\ y_2  \\ y_3  \\ \vdots  \\y_m  \end{pmatrix}$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I think I have found the matrix $X^tX$, but if I should take the inverse of it I get a $0$ in the denominator?

Comment: Which denominator? The inverse is not a fraction. Are    you the author of the linked question as well?

Answer (score 1):

$$y = \begin{pmatrix} \beta_1 & \beta_2 \end{pmatrix}\cdot
\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\  x_2 \end{pmatrix}+u $$