# OLS by matrixform

Tags: matrices, statistics, solution-verification, matrix-equations, economics

If I have the model:
$y = β_1x_1 + β_2x_2 + u$.
I have to show that the OLS estimator is:

[image]

I think that I have to use $\beta =\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2
\end{pmatrix}=(X^tX)^{-1}X^tY$. But I'm a but confused. Can someone write up the matrices X and Y? I only have to multiply the first coordinat in the $2\times1$, because I only have to show it for $\beta_1$?

Comment: This? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation

Comment: Similar title and timing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820319/ols-estimator-matrix-form

Comment: You don't need to write $2x1$ when you mean $2\times1. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$$\require{cancel} \xcancel{
X = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & x_{11} & x_{12} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_{n1} & x_{n2} \end{array} \right]. \qquad\qquad  Y = \left[ \begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{array} \right]. \qquad {}}
$$

Later edit: I failed to notice that the model proposed in the original posting does not have an intercept. So that means we have
$$
X = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} x_{11} & x_{12} \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ x_{n1} & x_{n2} \end{array} \right]. \qquad\qquad  Y = \left[ \begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{array} \right].
$$

Comment: Thank you. Now I get: $$X^TX=\begin{bmatrix}n & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i2}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1}X_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1}X_{i2}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i2} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1}X_{i2} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i2}X_{i2}\end{bmatrix}$$ and $$X^Ty=\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}X_{i1}\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}X_{i2}\end{bmatrix}$$ But it's not possible to find $(X^TX)^-1$. What do I do wrong?

Comment: @para Note that you don´t have a constant. In my view the column with the 1´s at X is not right. See the answer I´ve made at the linked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820319/ols-estimator-matrix-form?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yeah I thought that too. Then I get $$X^TX=\begin{bmatrix}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1}X_{i1} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1}X_{i2}\\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i1}X_{i2} & \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i2}X_{i2}\end{bmatrix}$$, but do I not get a problem to find the inverse again?

Comment: Why should there be a problem?  You get only a problem if all data points lie on the regression line-I think.

Comment: @para : $X^\top X$ has an inverse if the columns of $X$ are linearly independent. $\qquad$

Comment: @callculus : It doesn't matter if all the residuals are $0.$ The case where $X^\top X$ fails to be invertible is when the columns of $X$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: @para : $$ \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right]^{-1} = \frac 1 {ad-bc} \left[ \begin{array}{rr} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{array} \right]. $$

Comment: Sorry, that is correct, I was a bit confused with all these 
sum sign. Yes it succeeded now

Comment: @para : Remember that you can "accept" an answer.